# Want to develop a servlet container like tomcat

Tags: java

Actually I want to develop a simple servlet container like tomcat. It's purely my learning purpose. It would be very helpful if anyone can help and guide me where to start actually.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is far to vague

Comment: Your search engine of choice and the Tomcat source code seem like good places to start.

Comment: @Giann: Why vague?? Can't we develop tomcat?? Is it gonna be a nightmare or impossible task???

Comment: @nilanjan: That's a bit like learning to climb by climbing the Mt. Everest.

Comment: @Grist: yeah..but the thing is that tomcat source is huge enough to start with..Actually I need to know the end to end internal architecture of tomcat,then I can only proceed. It will also be helpful if someone can brief me the overview and the technicalities.

Comment: @space : Someone has climbed Mt. Everest. And for the last 4 years I am working on JAVA...I am aware of core java...this is gonna be my R&D. I din't know that someone's dream can be someone's joke.

Answer (score 2):

First, study the [Java Servlet API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/servlet/index.html) ([fundementals](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Servlets/Fundamentals/servlets.html)) to understand to understand the lifecycle of the Servlet. Now, we're on Servlet 3 specification (The Latest Tomcat) so you will have to decide which version of Servlet API you want to implement.

Comment: @elite: thanks. I know the servlet lifecycle. But I want to understand the architecture of tomcat,means how it works step by step. It would be better if u can provide me some architectural diagram.

Comment: @nilanjan, you will need to get the source code and study it yourself. My guess is that they're using a Facade pattern to handle HTTP requests. There's more to the container, so what part of the container do you want to focus on?

Comment: Actually I want to focus on handling multithreaded http request,handling the servlet life cycle..I don't want to implement everything.

Comment: @nilanjan, Tomcat source code is the starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from studying the Servlet API you can grab tomcat's source code and read it. Start by doing something very very simple, like write a container that is capable of accepting Http request.

Answer (score 0):

Start with Socket Programming. How server listen to request on port 80.

Then Start the Request Handler. How the request from the client will be treated and then send the response to the client.

Start it with single threaded environment and then go to multi-Threaded environment. To receive request from different clients.

Then you can start keeping sessions and so on...

Hope it will help you.

Comment: @ahmed: thanks a lot. can u help me doing it. Actually I mean to say that if you can help me step by step then I will go like that and I will share it with you to verify whether I am going right,obviously in your pastime.

Comment: Wel this is a huge asking. :(... you need a lot of time in developing and maintenance the server. I am not been able to give you that much time as i am already busy doing other stuffs. sorry about that.

Comment: ok...no issues...can u provide me some architectural diagram..so that it becomes easy to understand and start from somewhere.